# error with adb library dependencies on 64-bit ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

when trying to create my test project in an Ubuntu 12.1 machine:

```
adb install bin/opine_test-debug.apk
adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I go to install lib64ncurses (I am indeed running a 64 bit OS):

```
sudo apt-get install lib64ncurses5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib64ncurses5:i386 : Depends: lib64tinfo5:i386 (= 5.9-10ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libc6-amd64:i386 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And it turns out that the offending package is `libc-amd64`:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Conflicts: libc6-amd64:i386 but 2.15-0ubuntu20.1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I am officially stumped. What kind of problems is this?

Comment: Have you tried: apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6

Comment: that indeed did it. I'm thinking that i already some 32 bit libraries installed that were incompatible with the 64 bit ones I was trying to install. if you make an answer out of this i'll accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

`sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6`

Comment: If you have this issue with aapt as well, you will need to run the following: sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386

Answer (score 1):

```
*sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386
```

for running the emulator you need that additional package:

```
*sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386
```

then install ia32-libs:

```
*apt-get install ia32-libs
```